# Singleton class for http requests

Tags: flutter

Can you give some advice how to design class for api requests in flutter? I'm ios developer and I used singleton classes with alamofire. If you provide some code it would be great!

```
class Client: ApiBase {
    static let shared = Client()
    private override init() {}

    func login(phoneNumber: String, password: String, completion: @escaping(_ error: String?) -> Void) {
        let params: [String : String] = [
            "userId" : phoneNumber,
            "password" : password,
        ]

        baseRequest(route: ApiRouter.login(), params: params) { (response) in
            if let json = response.json {
                Session.current.sessionId = json["sessionId"].string
            }

            completion(response.error)
        }
    }
}
```

How login method called:

```
@IBAction func singin(_ sender: TransitionButton) {
    Client.shared.login(phoneNumber: "12312", password: "123") { (error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            // show error
            return
        }

        // navigate to home page
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In flutter you don't have to deal with the relative nastiness of IBActions, protocols as callback, or retain cycles, and you have `async` and `await` to help out.

There's a few ways you could do the API calls - one would be to simply put them right in the same code as your UI. That has downsides, but it is certainly readable.

```dart
class WhateverMyComponentIsState extends State<WateverMyComponentIs> {

  Future<String> _doLogin({@required String phoneNumber, @required String password}) async {
    final response = await http.post(LOGIN_URL, body: {'userId': phoneNumber, 'password': password})
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(body);
      return jsonResponse['sessionId'];
    } else {
      ... error handling

    }

  }

  String phoneNumber;
  String password; 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ...(
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          final sessionId = await _doLogin(phoneNumber: phoneNumber, password: password);

          ... do whatever - setState(() => loggedIn = true), or Navigator.push ...
        }
      ),
     )
  }
}
```

If you wanted, you could extract all of the api calls into a different class - they could be static methods, but that makes it so that it's harder to write good tests if you ever decide to do that.

My personal recommendation is to use a form of more or less 'dependency injection', by utilizing InheritedWidget to provide an implementation of a class that actually performs the login (and could hold the sessionId). Rather than implementing all of that yourself, though, you could use the [`ScopedModel` plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/scoped_model) which I personally like very much as it greatly reduces the amount of boilerplate needed.

If you use ScopedModel properly (which I'll leave as an exercise for you - I'm pretty sure there's other questions about that), you can use it or a class it provides to do the http request, and then have the `sessionId` stored in the ScopedModel.

The beauty of that is that if you were to ever get to writing tests (or have to deal with two slightly servers, etc), you could then replace the ScopedModel with a different ScopedModel which implemented the same interface but doesn't actually perform http requests or performs them differently.

Answer (score 0):

In flutter you should create a class something like this

```
class User {
  String name;
  String pass;


  User({
      this.name,
      this.pass,
      });

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    pass= json['pass'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['pass'] = this.pass;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Now create the list of type `User` class something like this

```
final List<User> user;
```

> Now call the URL (API) for user Auth

```
 Future<void> validateUsr() async {
    var client = new http.Client();


    try {
      var response = await client.get(
          'https://xxxxxxxx/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token?username=xxxxx2&password=xxxxxx');
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = json.decode(response.body);
        var list = data as List;
        setState(() {
         user=list.map<User>((i) => User.fromJson(i)).toList();

        });
      } else {
        print('Somthing went wrong');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    } finally {
      client.close();
    }
  }
```

Hope this helped you